# Scala Spark 1.5.2 RDD[Either[A,B]]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The issue I am having is I seem to have tumled down a dark path by trying to use scala's `Either` within an RDD.

My application reads data using a spark context into `RDD[String]`.

This `RDD[String]` is then parsed into `Left[A]` or `Right[B]` (`Either[A,B]`) as I want unparsable records to remain so I can sink them elsewhere.

I have come to the point where I would like to treat A and B differently... therefore try to call

```
left: RDD[A] = (x:RDD[Either[A,B]]).map(_.left.get)
```

The issue here is that if x doesn't have any errors (left side) this will throw an exception. I can try and catch the exception but map will still need me to return an `RDD[A]` which can't be done with `sc.empty[RDD]` or `.getOrElse`.

If anyone has a working solution or could please correct me on best practise I'm guessing Eithers are not meant to be used in conjunction with RDD's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
val left: RDD[A] = x.collect({case Left(x) => x})
```

I would put errors on the left and correctly parsed values on the right - that's how it's usually done. Scala 2.12 also has a right-leaning either, which formally encodes that convention.

Comment: would this collect pull back all the Left records to the driver application?

If I had 20 millions records for example this would be possible OOM

Comment: The spark naming of `collect()` is unfortunate. This collect is the "proper" `collect`, which does the same as `collect` on the stdlib. A better name for the spark `collect()` would be `materialize` or similar. Also see the type signature in the documentation, which should tell you everything about it.

Comment: okay thank you,
Finally, would I be wise to cache x before as I intend to also do 
val right: RDD[B] = x.collect({case Ritgh(x) => x})
Which would be able to re-use the cached value of x once computed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use `Either` in conjunction with `RDD`

Filter only want you want

```
rdd.filter(_.isLeft).map { case Left(a) => a}
```

or

```
rdd.filterNot(_.isRight).map { case Left(a) => a }
```

Comment: `rdd.map(_.left.getOrElse(defaultValueOfA))`

Comment: rdd.map {
  case Left(a) => a
  case Right(b) => defaultValueOfA
}
I would then have to filter default A values?

Comment: @AdamPitt just filter and keep only the left items